# Sass:Syntax Error Invalid CSS error with custom colors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently learning Ruby on Rails through the tutorials and I am getting this invalid CSS error after setting custom colors with Bootstrap at custom.css.scss using the blog template.

The error goes away if I remove the first three lines but I do not understand what is going on.

```
$navbar-default-bg: $312312;
$light-orange: #ff8c00;
$navbar-default-color: $light-orange;

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Here is my gem setup.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

Error code

```
Invalid CSS after "...ar-default-bg: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "$312312;"
(in /Users/wraithseeker/Desktop/blog/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:1)

<html>
<head>
<title>RecipeBox</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

> Invalid CSS after "...ar-default-bg: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "$312312;"

The line in question...

```
$navbar-default-bg: $312312;
```

`$312312` is not a valid color. You need `#312312`.

Comment: That is really foolish of me, looks like I still have a long road ahead in terms as I learn web development.